# How do I open a snackbar when two passwords are mismatched?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I'm working on a full stack application. I'm attempting to open up a snackbar in my signup component when the new user's password and confirm password do not match. I've had other's tell me that I need to pass the setOpenAlert method as props to my Signup method. What would that look like?

this is my snackbar component:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { Snackbar, IconButton, Button } from "@material-ui/core";
import CloseIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Close";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  close: {
    padding: theme.spacing(0.5)
  }
}));

const Alert = ({ alerts }) => {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);

  const setOpenAlert = () => {
    setOpen(true);
  };

  const handleClose = (event, reason) => {
    if (reason === "clickaway") {
      return;
    }

    setOpen(false);
  };

  return (
    <Snackbar
      anchorOrigin={{
        vertical: "bottom",
        horizontal: "left"
      }}
      open={open}
      autoHideDuration={6000}
      onClose={handleClose}
      ContentProps={{
        "aria-describedby": "message-id"
      }}
      message={<span id="message-id">Note archived</span>}
      action={[
        <Button key="undo" color="secondary" size="small" onClick={handleClose}>
          UNDO
        </Button>,
        <IconButton
          key="close"
          aria-label="close"
          color="inherit"
          className={classes.close}
          onClick={handleClose}
        >
          <CloseIcon />
        </IconButton>
      ]}
    />
  );
};

// Alert.PropTypes = {
//   alert: PropTypes.array.isRequired
// };

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  alerts: state.alert
});


export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Alert);
```

This is the component I'm trying to get the snackbar in. I know it the call would go in the handleOnSubmit()

```
import React, { useState} from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { setAlert } from '../../actions/alert'
import GoalIcon from "../GoalIcon";
import PropTypes from 'prop-types' 
import {
  TextField,
  Button,
  makeStyles,
  Container,
  CssBaseline,
  Grid
} from "@material-ui/core";

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  paper: {
    marginTop: theme.spacing(8),
    display: "flex",
    flexDirection: "column",
    alignItems: "center"
  },
  goalBook: {
    fontWeight: "500",
    fontFamily: "Ma Shan Zheng",
    color: "#424242"
  },
  submit: {
    margin: theme.spacing(2, 0, 2)
  },
  form: {
    marginTop: theme.spacing(5)
  }
}));

const Signup = (props) => {
  const classes = useStyles();

  const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
    first_name: "",
    last_name: "",
    email: "",
    password: "",
    password2: ""
  });

  const { first_name, last_name, email, password, password2 } = formData;

  const handleOnChange = e => {
    if (formData.error) {
      setFormData({ ...formData, error: false });
    } else {
      setFormData({ ...formData, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
    }
  };



  const handleOnSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (password !== password2) {
      props.setAlert("Yo password ain't correct", "danger")
      return setFormData({ ...formData, error: true });
    } else {
      console.log('success')
    }

  };

  return (
    <Container component="main" maxWidth="xs">
      <CssBaseline />
      <div className={classes.paper}>
        <GoalIcon />
        <form className={classes.form} onSubmit={e => handleOnSubmit(e)}>
          <Grid container spacing={1}>
            <Grid item xs={12} sm={6}>
              <TextField
                name="first_name"
                value={first_name}
                onChange={e => handleOnChange(e)}
                label="First Name"
                fullWidth
                variant="outlined"
                required
                margin="normal"
                autoComplete="none"
                autoFocus
              />
            </Grid>
            <Grid item xs={12} sm={6}>
              <TextField
                label="Last Name"
                name="last_name"
                value={last_name}
                onChange={e => handleOnChange(e)}
                fullWidth
                variant="outlined"
                required
                margin="normal"
                autoComplete="none"
              />
            </Grid>
          </Grid>
          <Grid container>
            <Grid item xs={12}>
              <TextField
                label="Email"
                fullWidth
                variant="outlined"
                required
                margin="normal"
                name="email"
                value={email}
                onChange={e => handleOnChange(e)}
                autoComplete="none"
              />
            </Grid>
            <Grid item xs={12}>
              <TextField
                error={formData.error}
                label="Password"
                name="password"
                value={password}
                type="password"
                onChange={e => handleOnChange(e)}
                fullWidth
                variant="outlined"
                required
                margin="normal"
              />
            </Grid>
            <Grid item xs={12}>
              <TextField
                error={formData.error}
                helperText={formData.error ? "Passwords do not match" : null}
                type="password"
                label="Confirm Password"
                fullWidth
                variant="outlined"
                required
                margin="normal"
                name="password2"
                value={password2}
                onChange={e => handleOnChange(e)}
              />
            </Grid>
          </Grid>
          <Button
            color="primary"
            variant="contained"
            fullWidth
            type="submit"
            className={classes.submit}
          >
            Sign Up
          </Button>
          <Link to="/" style={{ textDecoration: "none" }}>
            Already have an account? Login
          </Link>
        </form>
      </div>
    </Container>
  );
};

Signup.propTypes = {
  setAlert: PropTypes.func.isRequired
}

export default connect(null, {setAlert})(Signup);
```

And this is the top level component where everything comes together

```
import React from "react";
import "./App.css";
import LoginBox from "./components/layout/LoginBox";
import NotFound from "./components/layout/NotFound";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import Signup from "./components/layout/Signup";
import Alert from './components/layout/Alert'
// Redux
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import store from "./store";

const App = () => {
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <Router>
        <Alert/>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" component={LoginBox} />
          <Route exact path="/Signup" component={Signup} />
          <Route path="*" component={NotFound} />
        </Switch>
      </Router>
    </Provider>
  );
};

export default App;
```

https://github.com/Benjamin-Wofford/Goal-Book
(I tried uploading my project to a sandbox, but I get a status error. So I have the entire github project link listed here)

Answer (score 0):

Just render your `Alert` inside the `container` of the `Signup` component like below code

```js
{
  error && <Alert />
}
```

since you are setting `error = true` inside `handleOnSubmit` method.

So whenever there will be `error = true`, your `Alert` Snack-bar will be visible.

Comment: `const handleOnSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (password !== password2) {
      props.setAlert("Your password is incorrect", "danger")
      return setFormData({ ...formData, error: true && <Alert/>});
    } else {
      console.log('success')
    }` 

Did you mean like this? When I tried that setup, it isn't showing the Alert component when the passwords are mismatched.

Comment: @Benjamin-wofford, I had made changes, but not able to raise a PR in the given repo.

Comment: What error message did it give you? 

and what changes did you make?

Comment: I had raised couple of PRs please have a look.